# Python Programming - to modify a list item in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Question: # Write a program to modify the email addresses in the `records` dictionary to reflect this change

```
records = {57394: ['Suresh Datta', 'suresh@example.com'], 48539: ['ColetteBrowning', 'colette@example.com'], 58302: ['Skye Homsi','skye@example.com'], 48502: ['Hiroto Yamaguchi', 'hiroto@example.com'], 48291: ['Tobias Ledford', 'tobias@example.com'], 48293: ['Jin Xu', 'jin@example.com'], 23945: ['Joana Dias', 'joana@example.com'], 85823: ['Alton Derosa', 'alton@example.com']}
```

I have iterated through the dictionary and created a new list with the values and split the email at @ and was able to change the the email from .com to .org.

My approach was to join the changed email and change the values of the dictionary. However, I keep on getting a TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

my code :

```
lst2 = []

for value in records.values():
    lst2.append(value[1].split('@'))


for items in lst2:
    items[1] = 'examples.org'

for items in lst2:
    ','.join(lst2)
```

Comment: Quick note: I have not included the first part of the question. it is : The company's domain has changed from (example.com) to (example.org)

Comment: Ok, then how about my answer

Comment: problem in last line, you cannot use `','.join(lst2) `, `lst2` is two-dimensional array

Comment: Appreciate your help. I understand the mistake I've made.  Your answer worked as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your final for loop:

```
for items in lst2:
    ','.join(lst2)
```

You are joining should be joining items not lst2. However if you fix that it still won't work. You need to create a third list and add the values to it like this:

```
lst3 = []
for items in lst2:
    lst3.append('@'.join(items))
```

Then, lst3 will have the properly formatted emails.

Comment: @KKH Glad I could help! If you've solved your problem, click the green check on my answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a one-liner list-comprehension for, then iterate and do join the split of `i` with `','`, so try this:

```
print([','.join(i[1].replace('.com','.org').split('@')) for i in records.values()])
```

Output:

```
['suresh,example.org', 'colette,example.org', 'skye,example.org', 'hiroto,example.org', 'tobias,example.org', 'jin,example.org', 'joana,example.org', 'alton,example.org']
```

Or:

```
print(['@'.join(i[1].replace('.com','.org').split('@')) for i in records.values()])
```

Output:

```
['suresh@example.org', 'colette@example.org', 'skye@example.org', 'hiroto@example.org', 'tobias@example.org', 'jin@example.org', 'joana@example.org', 'alton@example.org']
```

Or if want to edit dict:

```
print({k:[i.replace('.com','.org') for i in v] for k,v in records.items()})
```

Output:

```
{57394: ['Suresh Datta', 'suresh@example.org'], 48539: ['ColetteBrowning', 'colette@example.org'], 58302: ['Skye Homsi', 'skye@example.org'], 48502: ['Hiroto Yamaguchi', 'hiroto@example.org'], 48291: ['Tobias Ledford', 'tobias@example.org'], 48293: ['Jin Xu', 'jin@example.org'], 23945: ['Joana Dias', 'joana@example.org'], 85823: ['Alton Derosa', 'alton@example.org']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
records = {57394: ['Suresh Datta', 'suresh@example.com'], 48539: ['ColetteBrowning', 'colette@example.com'], 58302: ['Skye Homsi','skye@example.com'], 48502: ['Hiroto Yamaguchi', 'hiroto@example.com'], 48291: ['Tobias Ledford', 'tobias@example.com'], 48293: ['Jin Xu', 'jin@example.com'], 23945: ['Joana Dias', 'joana@example.com'], 85823: ['Alton Derosa', 'alton@example.com']}
for key, value in records.items():
    new_data = []
    for data in value:
        new_data.append(data.replace('.com', '.org'))
    records[key] = new_data

print(records)
```

> {57394: ['Suresh Datta', 'suresh@example.org'], 48539: ['ColetteBrowning', 'colette@example.org'], 58302: ['Skye Homsi', 'skye@example.org'], 48502: ['Hiroto Yamaguchi', 'hiroto@example.org'], 48291: ['Tobias Ledford', 'tobias@example.org'], 48293: ['Jin Xu', 'jin@example.org'], 23945: ['Joana Dias', 'joana@example.org'], 85823: ['Alton Derosa', 'alton@example.org']}

Comment: I wasn't aware of the .replace method, it makes things much easier. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Glad I could help. I feel you should go for the nested loop, this will simplify you code. rather than going for multiple single  loops.